# The geometry of $\mathbb{F}_1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, affine-varieties

Over the years I have heard some people talking about a kind of geometry of $\mathbb{F}_1$. I will be very honest and admit that it does not make any sense to me.

The set $\mathbb{F}_1^n$ has precisely one point, and the variety associated to any polynomial is precisely the whole space. Everything looks trivial to me.

> What are they really talking about?

Comment: This is a large and vague subject; for starters see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element for some discussion and references. $\mathbb{F}_1$ is not a field, or for that matter even a ring; nobody knows what it actually is yet, there are just conjectures and desiderata.

Comment: It really looks like the plot of Alice in $\mathbb{F}_1$.

Comment: If you put a seed on a too poor field it will never germinate... An advice: do not spend time on such deadends...

Comment: There is a french plane called F1 which has a nice geometry :)

Comment: Is it because everything looks trivial for you that you post this question here and not in MathOverflow ? :-)

Comment: No, it is because I was sure I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the answers from a similar question on Math overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2300/what-is-the-field-with-one-element

The main things to note are that

1. there is no actual field with one element
2. there are many approaches to defining it
3. these approaches give various objects that "would be nice" to have in certain contexts, and generalise geometrical concepts in some appealing way